# Datastructure in Java to store table data that contains grouped elements

Tags: java, data-structures, grouping, tabular

[image]

What is the best way to represent tables in Java that contains grouped data as in above? The data is retrieved from the database which need to be processed and grouped. Final aim is to iterate over the data and render it to an html page. Performance is a major concern, The only solution I have in mind is to have Maps inside Maps where a Map stores a particular group name as 'key' and another Map as its 'value' which in-turn can represent another sub-group the similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object that can represent all your column data as member fields, then keep a list or set of these objects. Is there a particular reason you cannot do this?

Comment: thanks for checking this. The problem is that it will require several iterations over the objects to generate objects corresponding to rows where you see 'Total' counts, those values are not coming from database. Also suppose that we store the row next to 'Problem Type 1' in an object, that object wont contain the information regarding its 'Problem Type', 'Status' etc. My ultimate aim to have a datastructure which can be iterated and rendered as an html page.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to create yourself the datastructure and write your own iteration methods to be able to have full control over what it does.

Instead of creating a map of a map with another map, create a `Chart` which contains lists of `Problem`s (like a list for each type of problem), and the `Problem` would contain the status, the severity and all.

This way you can control the behaviour of the iteration inside each `Problem` and you can control the iteration over the collections of `Problem`. You can then sum the severities inside a `Problem` to get the subtotal. When you pass over all the problems (in `Chart`), you sum each severity type in a distinct member (`type1criticaltotal`, `type2mediumtotal`, etc. It could also be a map `type1total`), when you reach the end of all the list you sum all the criticals, all the mediums, etc. into their own members. (`criticaltotal`, `mediumtotal`, etc.) Because you created the method you have full control over the optimizations.